# Memory alignment in C-structs under Windows 32bits

Tags: c, memory, struct

Here is a snippet:

```
struct a {
  float* f;
  char c;
  int i;
  char z[4];
  double d;
  short s;
};

struct b {
   struct a a1;
   int j;
   struct a a2;
};
```

When I do a printf("%d\n",sizeof(struct a)), it emits to me 32... But when I do the same for the struct b, it emits 72 which I don't know how can be possible this, it should be 32+4+28(padding)+32 following the same calcs that I did to find out the previous result... can anyone tell me why is this happening?

Comment: Can you explain why you think this is wrong?  Why do you think the extra padding is necessary?

Comment: `struct a` requires 26 bytes (including padding in the middle) + 6 bytes at the end, for aligning the memory for the `double` in the struct (in case of an array). when You'r defining `int j` in `struct b` it can take 4 of the bytes from the padding at the end of `struct a` without disrupting the memory alignment for the `double`.

Comment: @RetiredNinja The extra padding should be 28 to align the integer to the other 2 structs( so all the members start on a 32 multiple)

Comment: @Myst in that case the sizeof would be 32+32=64  but it's not the case :(

Comment: @Bechma - You're totally right, except that the compiler won't "unpack" `struct a`, costing you 8 bytes for `int J` which you need in order to set the memory alignment for `a2` (so the double is aligned).

Comment: @Myst I understand, so the compiler will align the int as a multiple of 8 as the struct a has a double that takes 8, is that right?

Comment: Yap. The `double` has a memory alignment that effects `struct a`'s requirements. When you're using `struct a ` as a type after the `int J`, it's invoking it's requirement for 8 byte alignment, causing `int J` to pad to 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my calculations, `struct a` requires 26 bytes (including padding in the middle) + 6 bytes at the end. It looks something like this:

```
struct a {
  float* f;  // takes 4 bytes
  char c;    // takes 1 bytes + 3 padding
  int I;     // takes 4 bytes
  char z[4]; // takes 4 bytes
  double d;  // takes 8 bytes, sets a requirement for memory alignment
  short s;  // takes 2 bytes.
  // here there are 6 more bytes for padding required for array alignment.
};
```

The `double` in the struct means that `struct a` must be positioned on an 8 byte alignment mark, so that the `double` is correctly aligned.

Now, when we have `struct b`, we have:

```
struct b {
   struct a a1; // takes 32 bytes, REQUIRES and 8 byte alignment
   int j; // takes 4 bytes + 4 byte padding (for alignment).
   struct a a2; // takes 32 bytes, MUST start on an 8 byte alignment
};
```

I hope this wasn't homework or something... :-p

Comment: It wasn't homeworks, I'm studying this things and this question blocked my way... cheers!

Comment: @Bechma - I was kidding. I wouldn't have answered if I thought it were homework. I'm happy I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is aligned to more than multiples of 8 for the x86/amd64 architectures. See for example [Structure Alignment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa296569(v=vs.60).aspx) for Visual Studio. `struct a` and `struct b` have a `double` member, so they must be aligned at a multiple of 8 and their `sizeof` must be a multiple of 8; you can easily see why 32 is correct for `struct a`. The `int j` is 4 bytes, at a multiple of 4; since it comes immediately after `struct a a1` it need no padding, being placed a multiple of 8. `struct a a2` needs to be at a multiple of 8, so 4 bytes of padding are added. Overall, `struct b` needs 32 bytes for member `a1`, 4 bytes for member `j`, 4 bytes of padding (to bring `a2` to a multiple of 8) and 32 for member `a2` for a total of 72.